# How to validate that the user's password does not contain readable words or contain a predictable sequence of letters or numbers?

Tags: jquery, validation, passwords

I wanted to improve the registration form on my project by validating that the user's selected password is strong.

I was able to validate

- must be 12 characters long
- must have a lower case letter
- must have an upper case letter
- must have a number
- must have a symbol

What I want to add is to check that the password is strong enough and must not be sequential or readable. Eg.

- MyPassword123!
- ThisIsQwerTYuiop22\
- JameS@19@JameS
- a-B-333-4444-55555
- AbCdEfGhIjK-22

Is there are way to do this through Jquery?

Comment: Readable passwords are not a problem **if they are long enough** (12 characters is too short for a password)

Comment: Thank you for replying, Mark. Yes, I am now using **zxcvbn** to check password quality and offer a suggested passphrease through **GenPhrase** during registration and password reset.